# Is there a fast way to see all the active mesures in a Power BI report?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to siff through a large PBI report and for that I want to be able to determine the active measures and tables in the data model. In others words, I wanna be able to see what's being used from what's unused or obsolete in the model.

Is there, by any chance, a shortcut for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is RADACAD's amazing [PowerBI Helper Utility](https://radacad.com/power-bi-file-clean-up-in-a-few-steps).

This utility, once installed, is integrated in to the PowerBI external tools ribbon.

[image: RADACAD PowerBI Helper]

See the section at the link above around removing unused fields and measures.

> **Remove Not-used fields** If there is a field not used in any visual, filter, or other calculations, then this is a safe field to be
> removed. Power BI Help can identify these fields even if they are DAX
> calculated columns or measures. Using the dependency tree of the
> measure, it will identify if the field is used in another calculation
> that is used in a visual or filter.